# Creating a function based Index in Oracle DB using comparison operator

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, oracle12c

I'm using Oracle DB (Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production) and my table definition is like this:

```
Create table CardInfo (
Id Number not null,
BalanceInfo Decimal,
...
...
);
```

A lot of times this table will be queried like this:

```
select Id, ... from CardInfo where BalanceInfo > 0;
```

So, I'm trying to create a function based index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX balance_ix ON CardInfo (BalanceInfo > 0);
```

However, above statement gives following error:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
>   CREATE INDEX balance_ix ON CardInfo (BalanceInfo > 0);
>   Error report -
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   Cause:
>   Action:

So I changed my create index statement to following:

```
CREATE INDEX balance_ix ON CardInfo (BalanceInfo);
```

This executed fine and created the index. However, when I did a `Explain Plan` for my sql statement like this:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN 
  SET statement_id = 'ex_plan1' FOR
SELECT * FROM CardInfo WHERE BalanceInfo > 0;;

SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT 
  FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY(NULL, 'ex_plan1','BASIC'));
```

It produced the following output:

Plan hash value: 97071123

```
-------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name          |
-------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |               |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| CardInfo      |
-------------------------------------------
```

This means that it is not using the index that I created.

Could someone help, how can i create an index so that my sql statement uses it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: BalanceInfo seems to be a number column as you  are comparing it with zero. Why not just index BalanceInfo using normal index?. Create index CardInfoIdx on CardInfo(BalanceInfo); If you have large number of values satisfying BalanceInfo > 0, then FTS is better than, Index Scan.

Comment: The short answer to your question is somewhat hidden in Wernfried Domscheit's answer. Namely: assuming a relatively high fraction of balances will be greater than zero most of the time (as they are in real life), you will always get full table scans. Why? Because using an index is **in**efficient when a relatively large fraction (say, more than 20%) of the rows in the table will satisfy the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on Function-Based-Index then you may use

```
CREATE INDEX balance_ix ON CardInfo ( SIGN(BalanceInfo) );
```

Result of `SIGN(BalanceInfo)` can be -1, 0 and 1.

However, unless you create a BITMAP index (i.e. `CREATE BITMAP INDEX ...` Oracle will hardly use it because of cardinality of this index. But creating a BITMAP index also have other effects.

Another approach could be to make a partitionized table (List or Range partition). One partition for `BalanceInfo = 0` and one partition for the rest. Would be as this:

```
CREATE TABLE CardInfo (
    ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    BalanceInfo DECIMAL)
PARTITION BY LIST (BalanceInfo) (
    PARTITION P_zero_balance VALUES (0) INDEXING OFF,
    PARTITION P_other_balances VALUES (DEFAULT)
    )
ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

CREATE INDEX CARDINFO_BalanceInfo ON CARDINFO (BalanceInfo) LOCAL INDEXING PARTIAL;
```

Note, you don't need to create index entry for a constant value (i.e. `BalanceInfo = 0`), so I set `INDEXING OFF`.

If you prefer RANGE partition you could use

```
CREATE TABLE CARDINFO (
    ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
    BalanceInfo DECIMAL)
PARTITION BY RANGE (BalanceInfo) (
    PARTITION P_negative_balances VALUES LESS THAN (0),
    PARTITION P_zero_balance VALUES LESS THAN (0.001) INDEXING OFF,
    PARTITION P_positive_balances VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
    )
ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

CREATE INDEX CARDINFO_BalanceInfo ON CARDINFO (BalanceInfo) LOCAL INDEXING PARTIAL;
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I tried using the suggested 2nd approach, but wasn't able to figure out how to create a partition for BalanceInfo = 0.
In this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5011.htm#i2077034) :
`CREATE INDEX cost_ix ON sales (amount_sold)
   GLOBAL PARTITION BY RANGE (amount_sold)
      (PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1000),
       PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2500),
       `  , but how to create a partition for greater than and other partition for value equal to 0 ?